# How can I check what data is sent back to server in multi updatepanel forms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I have a few updatepanels in my asp.net webform. I’m doing some tests and I’m wondering how can I check what data is sent back to the server in different situations? Is there any tool or technique for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in Firefox.